# Angular2 Prevent queuing http requests when there is any pending request

Tags: angular

Let's assume I want to pull data from backend each 15 seconds. My code now looks like this:

**TestComponent:**

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    Observable.timer(0, 15000).subscribe(() => {
        this.callService();
    });
}
private callService(): void {
    this.testService.callBackendService().subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
    });
}
```

**TestService:**

```
public callBackendSerivce(): Subscribable<Data> {
     return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The problem is that when some error on backend occur and processing time will take more than 15 seconds this code will hit backend service once again, and again, no waiting for response. I want to prevent such behaviour and call service only when I received response from previous call. How to implement this?

I thought it should look like this:

**TestComponent:**

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.callService();
}

private callService(): void {
    this.testService.callBackendService().subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        this.subscribeToService();
    });
}

private subscribeToService(): void {
    this.timerSubscription= Observable.timer(15000).subscribe(() => {
        this.callService();
        this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    });
}
```

Two questions:

1. Is there any better solution to do this?
2. If no - does Observable.timer has method to get first result and automatically unsubscribe? It'll prevent adding this code:

   *this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();*

Answer (score 1):

According to second point, you have two possibilities:

```
Observable.first().subscribe(...)
```

or

```
Observable.take(1).subscribe(...)
```

`first()` means that **Observable** will emit only 1 item from the source. `take()` allows you to set how much times you want to subscribe (as argument).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `switchMap` operator on the timer like this:

```
Observable.timer(0, 15000).switchMap(() => this.callService()).subscribe();
```

This will call `callService` every 15 seconds.

If for any reason `callService` throws an error, the timer will automatically complete thanks to `switchMap`.

If  you want just the first value of `callService` you should just call it without the timer.

HTTP calls always complete after successfully returning a value, so they don't have to be unsubscribed from.

If you want `callService` called after 15 seconds you should use the delay on the `timer`.

`Observable.timer(15000).switchMap( ... )`

Regarding retrying after a failed attempt, check out the `retry` operator at http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retry

Comment: I want to prevent calling backend service if any http request is pending. In your example when there is any pending request I'll cancel this request and make new call. This is not what I'm looking for.